# How to install my custom Python package with its custom dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, package

I would like to find a way to install my own python package which depends on other custom python packages.

I followed this guide to create my own python packages: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.iao/en/latest/

For all packages, the minimal structure is:

```
myOwnPackage/
    myOwnPackage/
        __init__.py
    setup.py
```

Now, I created a package which depends on other custom packages. Its structure is:

```
myOwnPackage/
    dependencies/
        packageA
        packageB
    myOwnPackage/
        __init__.py
    setup.py
```

My question is: How to easily install `myOwnPackage` and its custom dependencies with pip ?

For the above example, I would like to install myOwnPackage, packageA and packageB when I call pip like that: `pip install myOwnPackage`

I did not find a way to include dependency names in setup.py like I can do for official python packages like `numpy`, pyqt5 etc.

I find a way to solve my problem partially by using a requirements.txt with pip:

`pip install -r requirements.txt myOwnPackage`

and here is how I wrote the requirement file:

```
./dependencies/packageA
./dependencies/packageB
```

I works well, but not when I have recursive dependencies like that:

```
myOwnPackage/
    dependencies/
        packageA/
            dependencies/
                packageC
            packageA/
                __init__.py
            setup.py
            requirements.txt
        packageB
    myOwnPackage/
        __init__.py
    setup.py
    requirements.txt
```

pip with the top-level requirements.txt will install myOwnPackage, packageA and packageB but it does not know that it has to install packageC which is a packageA dependency.

Any idea?

Comment: How are these packages made available? Are they published to pypi or a similar service? You can use the [`install_requires`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies) argument for `setup`. If the packages are not available on pypi, you can still declare them as dependencies, as described [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi). However if these are separate packages it feels a bit weird that they are listed in the package directories of other packages (instead of next to each other).

Comment: More details about my structure:
- these packages are not published to pypi
- each custom package is a single gitlab repository
- each dependency package is set as a submodule

I cannot set local path in `install_requires` option. Maybe it could work if I set `dependency_links` option with the gitlab url (with a token to allow the download).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can set a local URL in `dependency_links` such as `file:///path/to/dist`.

Comment: It works with a single file, but not with a directory (I did not find the specific scheme for a directory). And dependency_links is ignored by default. We need to call `--process-dependency-links` but it has been removed in last version of pip.

Answer (score 2):

I almost solved my problem.

I need to build each dependency with the following command: `python setup.py sdist` in order to create a single package file (tar.gz)

Then, I can call them in the top-package setup.py:

```py
...
dependency_links=["file:/local/path/myOwnPackage/dependencies/packageA/dist/packageA-0.1.tar.gz"],
install_requires=["packageA"],
...
```

Finaly, I run the following command to install `myOwnPackage` and its local dependencies:

`pip install . --process-dependency-links`

It installs all recursive dependencies if all repo are built and set correctly as describe above.

`--process-dependency-links` has been removed in last version of pip...

Comment: You can put the stuff in a `requirements.txt` and then use this to build and install your dependencies (see [this part of the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/index.html?highlight=--process-dependency-links#installing-from-wheels)). It won't be auto-discovered by `pip` but it's a mere `pip install -r requirements.txt` before the normal `pip install ...`. They disabled automatic installation of non-pypi resources for security reasons I think. If you want to install from an external source, you'd have to do so explicitly (via `requirements.txt` for example).

Comment: I currently use a requirements.txt to install my parent packages and all its dependencies. But it is not recursive. Recursive requirements.txt won't be auto-discovered. I can call the requirements.txt of a dependency package like that: `-r ./dependencies/yregmap/requirements.txt` but this way does not work for the requirements.txt of the dependency package because path are relative from the folder where I call the command `pip install -r requirements.txt .`

Comment: That's why, currently, I have to copy all recursive dependencies of all custom packages (parent package and all packages of all level of dependency) in the dependency folder of the parent package and call them from the requirements.txt.